# Get Current Item children by fast query

Tags: sitecore-query

Using Sitecore 8.2 and the content tree looks like:

```
sitecore
|_Content
  |_Home
    |_Products
      |_Product 1
      |_Product 2
    |_Services
      |_Service 1
      |_Service 2
```

The items `Products` & `Services` are of the same template which has a treelist field. The items that can be selected from the treelist should be the children of that Menu item.

For eg: For `Products`, author should see only Product 1, 2 in its tree list.  Similarly, for `Services`, he should see only Service 1, 2.

How can I write a query for the children path, in the template itself to achieve this.  For now I'm doing these for each item at item level.

```
fast:/sitecore/content/home/products/*  
fast:/sitecore/content/home/services/*
```

Comment: Did you try : "fast:/*"

Comment: @SitecoreClimber. Yes. That did not work. It shows the whole content tree

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In theory the correct syntax is `query:.` (`.` being self) but [there is a bug](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/p/271/1101#1101) which means it does not work as expected.

I would recommend not using `fast:` for performance reasons, instead set the Source of your Treelist field to the following:

```
query:self::
```

This will select the current item as the root of the Treelist field.